# django: redirect subdomain to another url

Tags: django, subdomain

In Django in the urls.py file, how do I write a url redirect so that login.domain.com does a 301 redirect to domain.com/login? I'm looking for a way to redirect a subdomain to a url. I realize this can be handled using ningx, however, I'd like to be able to maintain it in Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [3rd party apps](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains/blob/master/subdomains/middleware.py#L28) usually put this functionality into Middleware and use the [`process_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order) hook to take care of subdomain recoginition and then perform appropriate redirect.

Example displaying custom middleware and use of `process_request` from django-subdomains

```
class SubdomainMiddleware(object):
    """
    A middleware class that adds a ``subdomain`` attribute to the current request.
    """
    def get_domain_for_request(self, request):
        """
        Returns the domain that will be used to identify the subdomain part
        for this request.
        """
        return get_domain()

    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        Adds a ``subdomain`` attribute to the ``request`` parameter.
        """
        domain, host = map(lower,
            (self.get_domain_for_request(request), request.get_host()))

        pattern = r'^(?:(?P<subdomain>.*?)\.)?%s(?::.*)?$' % re.escape(domain)
        matches = re.match(pattern, host)

        if matches:
            request.subdomain = matches.group('subdomain')
        else:
            request.subdomain = None
            logger.warning('The host %s does not belong to the domain %s, '
                'unable to identify the subdomain for this request',
                request.get_host(), domain)
```

Comment: Where am I putting the redirect so that login.domain.com redirects to domain.com/login?

Comment: @wwwuser you could put it in `process_request`